# How to save mat tree expansion model and apply it?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I need to save current expanded nodes of mat tree close all and then expand them all again.
My approach was like this:

Save the expansion model

```
treeControl = new NestedTreeControl<NavbarNode>((node: NavbarNode) => return node.children);

 this.prevExpansionModel = this.treeControl.expansionModel.selected;
      this.treeControl.collapseAll();
```

and then apply it

```
this.prevExpansionModel.forEach(object => this.treeControl.expand(object));
```

It works when I do it this way but the nodes that got expanded will no longer work and I can't toggle them. (I cannot toggle those that have been expanded, other ones I can expand and work normally)

Comment: Can you show working demo of this problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a previous expansion model var where you will save the expansion model.

```
public prevExpansionModel: NavbarNode[] = [];
```

If the navbar is open save the expansion model, close all node and close the navbar.
If it's open then open sidenav and apply the expansion model.

```
private toggleMatTree() {
    if (this.navbarStatus === NavbarStatus.OPEN) {
      this.prevExpansionModel = this.treeControl.expansionModel.selected;
      this.treeControl.collapseAll();
    } else {
      this.treeControl.collapseAll();
      this.prevExpansionModel.forEach(object => this.treeControl.expand(object));
    }
 }
```

Here is my logic for opening the sidenav, maybe it will help you.

```
public toggleSideNav() {
    if (this.navbarStatus === NavbarStatus.OPEN) {
      this.toggleMatTree();
      this.navbarStatus = NavbarStatus.CLOSED;
    } else {
      this.toggleMatTree();
      this.navbarStatus = NavbarStatus.OPEN;
    }
    return this.navbarStatus;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

To expand on the previous answer the tree works by reference, so if you persist this data in the session or local storage you need to first get the tree node instance.

Here's an example of a function that I use to save the state in local storage:

```js
  private persistTreeState() {
    // load tree if it exists
    const previousState = localStorage.getItem(this.key);
    if (previousState) {
      const selected = JSON.parse(previousState);
      if (selected) {
        const nodes = this.treeControl.dataNodes;
        selected.forEach((id: string) => {
          const node = nodes.find(n => n.id === id);
          if (node) {
            this.treeControl.expand(node);
          }
        });
      }
    }

    // save tree state when it changes
    this.treeControl.expansionModel.changed.subscribe(state => {
      const selectedIds = this.treeControl.expansionModel.selected.map(n => n.id);
      localStorage.setItem(this.key, JSON.stringify(selectedIds));
    })
  }
```